# Javascript error replace on a string and url redirection

Tags: javascript, parsing, redirect, localhost

I wrote the following code, but there is a strange issue:
the algorithm is working but my localhost redirect to another port
for example :
http://localhost:8080 become http://localhost:8180 (or something like that) 
When i put in comment the following line the port doesn't change

```
url = url.replace(url[url.indexOf("&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=") + 27], toAppend);
```

so I'm sure the problem become from the line below but I don't know why and I don't know if there is another way to do this ?

```
 if (url.includes("&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=")) {
    url = url.replace(url[url.indexOf("&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=") + 27], toAppend);
    obj.href = url;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @VisioN I have an URL like : "http://localhost:8080/netmg/view/home#agregateShowMode=site&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=1&displayPath=AME%2FNORTH%20AMERICA%2F" an I want to change "1" of "&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=1" to another number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344553/javascript-error-replace-on-a-string-and-url-redirection/30344675#comment48782229_30344553) the easiest way would probably be using regular expression and [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
obj.href = url.replace(/(&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=)\d+/, '$1' + another_number);
```

This will check if the given parameter was actually a number and will make a replacement.

Comment: @JeromeCampeaux You are very welcome `:)` The good thing is that you don't even need to make any check if the parameter exists in the string: regex will do everything for you.

Comment: yeah very useful for this kinf of things ^^